# Deleting a complete folder in Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

How can I delete a complete folder in redis, using DEL command OR in C# in StackExchange.Redis.

```
SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1:somekey1
SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1:somekey2
SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder2:somekey1
```

How can I Del SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1 so remaining keys are

```
SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder2:somekey1
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a "folder" in redis, and no functionality to `del` based on a pattern. Options:

- use a *database*; you can have an arbitrary number of databases (each is numbered, the default is 0), and you can discard a *database* in a single operation: `flushdb` - so keep all this associated data in one database and you're sorted
- use `scan` to iterate the matching keys, issuing a `del` for each match

note that `scan` is a *server* command, so you need:

```
const int db = 0;
var server = muxer.GetServer(...);
var db = muxer.GetDatabase(db);
foreach(var key in server.Keys(db, "SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1:*",
    pageSize: 500))
{
    db.KeyDelete(key, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
}
```

the `FireAndForget` allows you to ignore the individual replies, which means you aren't bound by latency and you don't have TPL overheads.

Fundamentally, though: redis *is not meant to be used like this* - if you find yourself scanning keys, *you are doing something wrong*. A more typical implementation might be to use a *hash* to store the folder (which each key/value pair inside the hash being the contents) - then deleting the hash is one operation. Alternatively, use a *set* to store the keys of the items inside each logical folder.

Hash approach:

```
hash = SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1
              key = somekey1, value = ...
              key = somekey2, value = ...
hash = SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder2
              key = somekey1, value = ...
```

Set approach:

```
set: SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1
              somekey1
              somekey2
set: SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder2
              somekey1
string: SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1:somekey1
              value
string: SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder1:somekey2
              value
string: SomeFolder1:SomeSubfolder2:somekey1
              value
```